# Dynamically change the background of statusbar, while maintaining transparency

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-statusbar, android-navigationview

### Context

I have a base activity which contains a `drawer navigation` from the example in android studio. I made the `statusbar` transparent and I want the menu to slide under it allowing its color to overflow into the transparency like this:

(notice the blue on the right)

[image]

However on default it looks like this:

[image: Android navigation drawer]

### Question

The blue color is from the theme colorPrimaryDark, however I want to dynamically change this color, so I can't rely on the theme. Is there any way to dynamically/programmatically set the color?

### Things I've tried

- Adjusting the color of the decor view; `getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.White)`
- Setting color of the statusbar and use the flag
  `DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS`:

  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
  window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
  window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
  window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
  }

(Sorry for the poor coding block, it doesn't want to listen)

This will not make it transparent as the first image, but simply a solid color.

- Changing the color of the rootView `anyView.getRootView().setBackgroundColor()`

### XML file: root_controller.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        tools:openDrawer="end">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- toolbar -->
            <include android:id="@+id/toolbar_group"
                layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

### XML file toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

### RootController activity

```
public class RootController extends AppCompatActivity implements
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        rootView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.root_controller, null);
        drawer = (DrawerLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) drawer.findViewById(R.id.main_content);

        targetView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, frameLayout, true);

        initMenu(drawer);
        super.setContentView(rootView);
    }

private void initMenu(DrawerLayout drawer){

        // get toolbar
        toolbarGroup = rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_group);
        initToolbarGroup(toolbarGroup, "test");



        // get the navigation view
        nav = (NavigationView) drawer.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        nav.setBackgroundColor(ColorDelegate.getNavColor());
        Menu menu = nav.getMenu();

        // set navigation listener
        nav.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        // ... fill menu
    }
```

Comment: you got your answer?

Comment: I've never achieved the desired effect, but I'm not working on that project anymore so I wouldn't be able to verify. Thanks for your interest though.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this in your `Activity`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    String dynamicColor = "#99000000";
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); /*You were missing this*/
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(dynamicColor));
}
```